# SDL2 can't render PNG file as texture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am trying to make a simple racing game with C++ using SDL2. When i tried rendering my car asset(PNG Image) it simply did not render saying in the console that it couldn't access the file. Note that the source files are located in an exclusive directory (src/), the headers are in /include and the images are located in /assets. Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Headers/RenderWindow.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init has failed..." << std::endl;
    }
    if (!(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG)))
    {
        std::cout << "IMG_Init has failed" << std::endl;
    }

    RenderWindow window("Untitled Racing Game", 1280, 720);

    SDL_Texture *blueCar = window.LoadTexture("../assets/blue_car.png");

    bool run = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (run)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                run = false;
            }
        }

        window.Clear();
        window.Render(blueCar);
        window.Display();
    }

    window.CleanUp();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

RenderWindow.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

class RenderWindow
{
public:
    RenderWindow(const char *title, int width, int height);
    SDL_Texture *LoadTexture(const char *filePath);
    void CleanUp();
    void Clear();
    void Render(SDL_Texture *texture);
    void Display();

private:
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};
```

RenderWindow.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Headers/RenderWindow.hpp"

RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const char *title, int width, int height)
    : window(NULL), renderer(NULL)
{
    window = (SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window Failed to Load. Error " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}
SDL_Texture *RenderWindow::LoadTexture(const char *filePath)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, filePath);

    if (texture == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture, " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    return texture;
}
void RenderWindow::CleanUp()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
void RenderWindow::Clear()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
}
void RenderWindow::Render(SDL_Texture *texture)
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
}
void RenderWindow::Display()
{
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Comment: ***saying in the console that it couldn't access the file*** I bet the file is not where you told it to look. Make sure you know were the current working directory is to use a path that is relative to that.

Comment: I specified in the code that the file is located in a different folder and that it had to move to the previous directory to find it.

Comment: The original `/assets` would look at the root folder of your filesystem. That is an absolute path when it starts with a / Now I see you changed it to `../assets` but you have to make sure that this is correct based on whatever your working directory is.

Comment: @drescherjm in this context you would have to move up a directory to reach `/assets` so i guess it should be working.